# Ubuntu 22.04 will not boot on HP laptop

Tags: boot, grub2, usb, uefi

Ubuntu 22.04 won't boot on an HP laptop.

I have created a bootable USB drive to install Ubuntu. The drive won't boot on the HP laptop, but the USB works normally on other computers (tested on one other laptop and one desktop computer, both worked fine). Then, I took out the SSD and installed Ubuntu on that drive through a different computer. The installation never properly worked. While I was able to boot it for a while, it then completely froze after a few minutes of use. It was also rather slow to use for those few minutes that it did work. Now, the computer won't boot Ubuntu at all.

So, I re-flashed the USB again and verified it worked. I am now trying to get Ubuntu to boot from the USB on the HP laptop, but am unable to do so. This is the error I get after choosing the option "try or install Ubuntu":
[error log image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPTXd.jpg)

If I choose "Ubuntu (safe graphics)" I get the same error. The log is slightly different, notably, the debugfs radeon stuff is missing as expected.

I have tried turning safe boot on or off in the BIOS, both options produced the same result. I have also tried enabling legacy boot in BIOS, which produced the same log as the first image, but without the last line, where the error is actually printed out. So, the log ended at after debugfs radeon lines.

The laptop itself is a 17 inch HP Notebook. I was unable to find any other product name (such as perhaps Pavilion, that is likely because it is probably a low end model). The product number is Z9C83EA#BED. It has Intel Core I3-6006 processor and 4GB of RAM. It looks like it is from 2017. The laptop does not have a battery.

Comment: Does the machine have the min hardware for Ubuntu 22.04? Have you verified the ISO you downloaded? https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-verify-ubuntu#1-overview Have you followed the offical tutorial on how to install? https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview

Comment: Safe boot should be off. You have not said if it is dual boot or only Ubuntu.

Comment: I have verified the SHA256 cheksum of the ISO file. I have not followed the tutorial, but have installed Ubuntu many times before successfully. Ubuntu will not boot from the USB stick either, so I had to install it to the drive using another computer and then transfered the drive. I am not dual booting, the only OS on the computer is Ubuntu.

Comment: Same thing happened with me with HP Elitebook